# Winamp: Generating 'dynamic playlists' from file playlists -OR- mass-tagging by file playlist

Tags: music, tags, winamp, playlists

I sort my songs into a variety of playlists corresponding to different 'moods' I might have *as I listen to them*, and some songs fit for more than one kind of mood (e.g. a jazz song might be 'stylish' and 'emotional', or something to that effect).  I also give them star ratings for a general sort of opinion about them.

I want to filter and sort my media library by the moods I want or don't want, as well as by star rating.  *I can't seem to use Winamp's dynamic playlists to generate lists from existing filesystem playlists (e.g. songs in a given .m3u files).  Hand-tagging files with Winamp's tag editor is a royal pain.  It's trouble enough just giving a star rating and sorting into playlists as is.*

If there is there a way to *mass tag (with appending instead of overriding?)* songs within each playlist with mood words to allow me to create dynamic playlists, I'd be fine (for now).  *It'd be nice if I could do this via some kind of hotkey for each song, too.  I'm looking to see if I can use a macro program or something to do that, though.*

<strike>***Edit:*** Problem!  I can't easily get into my winamp playlists on the file system!  They're apparently stored in unlabeled .m3u8 files in Winamp's AppData folder.  I can get to them, but this is inconvenient.</strike>

***Edit:*** Okay, I can use Dropbox (Ctrl+Shift+D) in Winamp to work around this annoyance.  Somewhat.

*Note: Italics are recent edits.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like MP3tag to tag your songs corresponding to your mood. Just add a custom tag for your purpose. You can use winamp itself for tagging, but I find MP3tag more convenient.
After that, you can use dynamic playlists in Winamp.

Comment: Alright, I got as far as adding custom tags, but I can't seem to get dynamic playlists to be using them.  What's the query I need?

I don't want to cannibalize an existing tag field, if I can avoid it (which seems to work, though).

Comment: The 'custom' query appears not to recognize tag fields that aren't in the main list.  This is odd.

Comment: In Winamp in the 'custom' query you should have a query generator where you can pick some tags. Your own tag is not in the list, but you can type your own query in the text box below. Please, try 'mood=="sad"' (if mood is the name of your custom tag). Does this work?

Comment: Evidently not.  I hope I'm not simply doing something wrong, though.  Also, it appears the set of valid fields is even more limited than what is available in the list (basically only the ones visible in the ID3v2 tab under the file info dialog).  That's my theory, at least...

Comment: Update: Not sure about that theory, though. I've been trying to use the Category field to store my tags. Turns out Winamp's 'Category' is actually represented 'contentgroup' as far as Mp3tag is concerned, for one little bit of confusion. Also, I need to select the option 'Read metadata on selected items' to get that particular tag field to update in Winamp's media library. BUT THIS REMOVES THE STAR RATINGS!!!  Grr...

Comment: Do you stop and restart Winamp after retagging your files externally? I noticed that the metatags are not updated automatically. Is the star rating being saved as mp3 tags?

Comment: The star rating appears to be in an internal database. The 'Import/Export Database' functions seem to be the only way to save/recover them, apparently.

Comment: And after some testing it seems I wasn't wrong earlier in that rescanning the watch folders updates the meta-data en-mass within winamp.  It does appear to destroy the star data for modified files, though...?  But I can use 'Import Database' to recovers these.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible in [ITunes](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030409021945127) <- *read the article probably it could be relevant.*

One more must [see article.](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/05/17/moody-mood-based-itunes-tagging-and-playlists/) of an app for itunes called Moody

*These are just some leads please don't be mad if they are not what you want* ;)